# Angular - problem connecting to API via http (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

Tags: angular, http, cors

I'm trying to get data from API using http (angular). If I call the function via `ngOnInit`, the data is downloaded correctly:

```typescript
handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    return throwError(() => new Error('Something bad happened; please try again later.'));
}

header4 = new HttpHeaders({
  'x-api-key': this.key,
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
});

listaProduktow: any = [];  

getProducts() {
  this.http.get(this.productUrl + "?resultsLimit=2", { headers: this.header4 })
  .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
  .subscribe(data => {
     this.listaProduktow = data;
     console.log(data);
   });
  console.log('products loaded');
}
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log('working!');
  this.getProducts();
}
```

However, if I want to use the function via an event (button click):

```html
<button (click)="getProducts()">Szukaj</button>
```

it throws an error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://xxxxxx.yourtechnicaldomain.com/api/admin/v3/products/descriptions?type=id&ids=10. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 404.
```

I'm using:
Angular CLI: 17.2.0
Node: 21.6.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 10.3.0

I tried using services, running the apk directly from the server... most of the suggestions from Google didn't help either.
I'm not an advanced Angular user - maybe it's a configuration problem?

Comment: Considering timing and asynchronous behavior - is the API call triggered from your event happening before the headers are ready? (Have you tried logging to see if the headers are as expected?)

Comment: You have to use `Access-Control-Allow-*` in backend not in client.

Comment: "running the apk directly from the server" Is this some kind of Android app or something? In any case, the reason for the error is likely due to the different context you are in when you run something from an event handler vs running the code from ngOnInit or any other place. I suggest creating a new function that calls `getProducts()` and set the event handler to that new function. Or move the HTTP call to an Angular Service, which is really where it should be anyway.

Comment: @BxtchCraft: I tried to simplify the function as much as possible to try to retrieve the data first. I will add the rest once I manage to download the data.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: I just tried to run the apk from the server (with IP address and SSL) and not from localhost, because I thought that was the problem

Comment: Do a search for `apk` in your favorite search engine. I guarantee that almost all of the first page of results will be about Android and [the apk file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apk_%28file_format%29). I don't know what apk refers to when it comes to Angular; I've never heard it used in this context. Perhaps you're doing something different that needs to be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

Adding such headers on frontend side usually don't work. You need to allow your origin on the server. And the reason why it works in `ngOnInit` might be because `getProducts()` executed as part of the initialization process of your Angular component. At this point, the browser may not enforce CORS restrictions as strictly because it's treated as part of the initial page load.

Comment: this would explain why data is downloaded during initialization and later not. That surprised me the most. I will try to add Access-Control-Allow-* to the backend and let you know if it worked.
Peace!

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. I enabled angular CORS via proxy. Here's link with step-by-step instructions (if anyone needs): https://dev-academy.com/angular-cors/.
It was quite simple.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).